# Pandas : Dot product shape mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make dot products of some columns in my dataset:

```
df_disorders_3col =  df.iloc[:,disorders_indexes]
df_disorders_3col.drop([5278, 10122, 10124, 10125, 10126], axis=0, inplace=True)
df_disorders_3col = df_disorders_3col.astype(int)
df_disorders_3col['Disorders'] = df_disorders_3col.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
df_disorders_3col.head()
```

but I get this error when running this block of code:

```
ValueError: Dot product shape mismatch, (10133, 38) vs (498,)
```

this is a sample of my data:

```
>>>df_disorders_3col.sample(5)
    HasDiabetes HasHypertension HasCardiacDisease ...  HasMS    HasPregnancyHypertension    HasPregnancyDiabetes
752 0       0       0           1   0               0

6312    0       0       0           0   0               0

6984    1       0       0           0   0               0

9016    0       0       0           0   0               1

8923    0       0       0           0   0               0
5 rows × 38 columns
```

also this is the shape of `df_disorders_3col`:

```
>>>df_disorders_3col.shape
(10133, 38)
```

and `df`:

```
>>>df.shape
(10138, 498)
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: It looks like you shouldn't have droped those columns in the second line (`10138 - 5 = 10133`). You may also have to transpose a `df_disorders_3col`.

Comment: you are now using the shape of df.columns on the dataframe df_disorders_3col. df_disorders_3col.dot(df_disorders_3col.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',') thats the reason for the error, using assign and query would make your code a lot more readable.